# Adding arrays to a collection

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create a collection of arrays. But I get an error on the first one. What is wrong ?

```
lastPrev = shPrev.Range("a15000").End(xlUp).Row
'load the arrays
For Each c In shPrev.Range("A10:A" & lastPrev)
    ar = c.Offset(0, 11).Resize(1, 4)
    col.Add CStr(c.Value2), ar     'type mismatch error here
Next c
```

I checked in debug mode, the key has a string value, and my array is a nice...array.

Comment: Does your array has value(s)?

Comment: @Zac Array is made by reading a range. Some cells will be empty

Comment: You have the [method signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Collection.Add` reversed. It's `Item` first, not `Key`.

Comment: @Comintern That was it, THANKS. Can you make it an answer ?

Comment: Nah, the answer would basically be "hit F2 and check the object browser". If you think it's useful, self-answering is completely fine around here.

Comment: @Comintern object browser is overkill, intellisense shows parameter types already ;-)

Comment: Note that if `c.Value2` contains an error value (e.g. `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, etc.), you'll get a *type mismatch* error for trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: Adding to @Comintern's comment: If you want Key to be first, use named parameters: `col.Add Key:=CStr(c.Value2), Item:=ar`